# psycopg2 replace '%5C' with '\' backslash

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I tried to decode the URLs in AWS Redshift. When I ran the following code on SQL Workbench, it was totally fine. However, when I use the same code via psycopg2, it gave me the error message `ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "D" LINE 35: ,'%5D',']')) as ...`

code:

```
SELECT *,
REPLACE(LEFT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.url, 'keywords=([a-zA-Z0-9]+[%+])*[a-zA-Z0-9]*') from 10), t1.extracted_search_value), 100),'%5C','\\') as parsed_search from new_table t1 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the '%' character is being seen as a wildcard character.  In Oracle % is a wildcard but only when using LIKE.  Not sure if this would work but try using the ascii value for the percent character.  `chr(37) || '5C'` as opposed to `'%5C'`.  Who knows, perhaps it's cause of your grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following SQL in python it should work. I have tested it using psycopg2

Basically you have two backslashes in your SQL, Postgres documentation has

*Use \\ if you need to put a literal backslash*

I have replaced `\\` from your code with `\\\\`

```
SELECT *,
REPLACE(LEFT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.url, 'keywords=([a-zA-Z0-9]+[%+])*[a-zA-Z0-9]*') from 10), 
t1.extracted_search_value), 100),'%5C','\\\\') as parsed_search from new_table t1 
LIMIT 10
```

For more explanation refer to section 9.7.3. POSIX Regular Expressions on the following link 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Please let me know if this solves your problem.